# Datepart function in oracle

Tags: oracle

I have some sample records in Oracle 12

```
Date_Time               Item
10/1/2012 12:05:00 AM   3
12/3/2012 06:00:00 AM   2
11/8/2012 14:05:05 PM   10
12/9/2012 16:00:59 PM   5
```

I like to aggregate the Item field based on military time or in three different times: 00:00:00AM to 05:59:00AM, 06:00:00AM to 15:59:00PM, and 16:00:00PM to 23:59:00PM. I was able to use the Datepart function in SQL to do this. I was wondering what function in Oracle 12 that allows me to count the Item between these three different times.

My desired output would be:

```
Date_Time                  Count
00:00:00AM to 05:59:00AM = 3
06:00:00AM to 15:59:00PM = 12
16:00:00PM to 23:59:00PM = 5
```

Comment: This is not clear. What do you want the result to be? How are you "aggregating" - by `SUM()`? What are the numbers in the `Item` column - item identifiers? Or item counts? Are you aggregating by time-of-day, regardless of date?

Comment: Also, you probably want < 6 a.m. and < 4 p.m. You should use EITHER military notation OR a.m./p.m., 16:00:00PM doesn't make sense in any software. And you left out 15:59:33, for example. You really want < 6 a.m. and < 4 p.m.

Comment: That is pretty strange - do you want the result in three rows, not in three columns?

Comment: @ mathguy, I apologize for the late response. I am testing my code now using your methodology. Thank you and everyone else's input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In oracle, date datatype contains date+time ,so you just need just use group by

```
SELECT Date_Time, COUNT(*) item FROM YOUR_TABLES
GROUP BY Date_Time;
```

NEW Answer:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(DATE_TIME,'HH24') time, count(*) FROM YOUR_TABLE
WHERE TO_CHAR(DATE_TIME,'HH24') >= '00'
AND TO_CHAR(DATE_TIME,'HH24') < '06'
GROUP BY TO_CHAR(DATE_TIME,'HH24')
UNION ALL
SELECT TO_CHAR(DATE_TIME,'HH24') time, count(*) FROM YOUR_TABLE
WHERE TO_CHAR(DATE_TIME,'HH24') >= '06'
AND TO_CHAR(DATE_TIME,'HH24') < '16'
GROUP BY TO_CHAR(DATE_TIME,'HH24')
UNION ALL
SELECT TO_CHAR(DATE_TIME,'HH24') time, count(*) FROM YOUR_TABLE
WHERE TO_CHAR(DATE_TIME,'HH24') >= '16'
AND TO_CHAR(DATE_TIME,'HH24') < '00'
GROUP BY TO_CHAR(DATE_TIME,'HH24');
```

and if your table is huge :
first :partition it
second: create local functional index on TO_CHAR(DATE_TIME,'HH24:MI:SS')

Comment: @ Vahid, i was thinking to use the case statement to group the records. i have kkk records.

Comment: @joe, if you want calculate count of items per second, just you can you group by clause

Comment: @joe, if you have millions records in your table, i recommend  you first partition your table per day

Comment: @joe, if you're time in all of days is fix you can use my new answer

Comment: can i use your new Answer as a nest query and write something like case when time between 0 and 5 then '00:00:00 to 05:59:00'...?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132725/discussion-between-joe-and-vahid).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `date_time` column is datatype `DATE`, we can use the TO_CHAR function to extract a two character representation... in the range 00 to 23.

(The selected answer demonstrates this approach to extracting the "hour" from an Oracle DATE.)

Assuming that we want every non-null time value to fall into one of three time ranges... that is, if we don't want any of time values to be omitted because of a crack/gap in between the ranges, and we don't want any overlap in the ranges...

We can use a simple "less than" tests in a CASE expression.

Consider a time close to a boundary: '05:59:33'.  That's after `05:59:00` but before `06:00:00`.  If we want that included in the first range, we can just test for hour < '06'.

If was grouping the rows into three ranges, and I wanted a total of the `item` column, I'd do something like this:

```
SELECT CASE
         WHEN TO_CHAR( t.date_time ,'HH24') < '06' THEN '00:00:00 to 05:59:59'
         WHEN TO_CHAR( t.date_time ,'HH24') < '16' THEN '06:00:00 to 15:59:59'
         WHEN TO_CHAR( t.date_time ,'HH24') < '24' THEN '16:00:00 to 23:59:59'
       END AS time_range
     , SUM(t.item)
  FROM mytable t
 GROUP
    BY CASE
         WHEN TO_CHAR( t.date_time ,'HH24') < '06' THEN '00:00:00 to 05:59:59'
         WHEN TO_CHAR( t.date_time ,'HH24') < '16' THEN '06:00:00 to 15:59:59'
         WHEN TO_CHAR( t.date_time ,'HH24') < '24' THEN '16:00:00 to 23:59:59'
       END
```

and add an `ORDER BY` clause if I want the results returned in a particular order.

If the table contains any NULL values of `date_time`, the query above will also return a fourth `time_range` with a NULL value.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you would get the desired result in three columns (rather than three rows), which makes more sense for most applications. You can change this easily to get the result in rows instead.

Note that if `dt` is any date in Oracle, `dt - trunc(dt)` is the number of days (a fraction with value less than 1) since midnight.

```
select sum(case when dt-trunc(dt) <   6/24 then item else 0 end) as morning,
       sum(case when dt-trunc(dt) >=  6/24 
                 and dt-trunc(dt) <  16/24 then item else 0 end) as daytime,
       sum(case when dt-trunc(dt) >= 16/24 then item else 0 end) as evening
from   your_table
;
```